# filter dataframe based on two columns of another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, conditional-statements

Here the two simulated dataframes:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5), type=c("A","G","D","B","C","R","U","A","T","E"))

df_2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7), type=c("A","Y","Q","B","C","R","U","E","J","A"))

ID type       ID type
1   A         1   A
1   G         1   Y
1   D         2   Q
2   B         2   B
2   C         3   C
3   R         4   R
4   U         5   U
4   A         5   E
4   T         6   J
5   E         7   A
```

I want to keep only rows from df_2 that have equal ID AND type of df_1, obtaining:

```
ID type
1   A
2   B
5   E
```

I tried to use the following code but it doesn't work properly

```
data <- df_2 %>% 
          filter(ID %in% df_1$ID & type==df_1$type)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you need is `dplyr::intersect`.

```
library(dplyr)

dplyr::intersect(df_1, df_2)

  ID type
1  1    A
2  2    B
3  5    E
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I have other columns in the dataframe (not included in the condition), which I want to keep in the final dataframe?

Comment: @Sabri. then the `inner_join()` proposed by other will be more useful, since it allows you to choose which column(s) to join

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `inner_join()`

```
  df_2 %>% 
    inner_join(df_1, by = c("ID", "type"))
```